# Problem with changing the location of TextArea in JFrame when I have JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing

My code brings text area on the left top corner of the frame. How can I change the location in the frame? [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlZoQ.png)

```
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JSP");
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scroll.setSize( 100, 200 );
        scroll.getViewport().setViewPosition(new java.awt.Point(100, 50));
        frame.add(scroll);
        frame.setSize(250, 300);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

Comment: `BorderLayout` is the default layout for the content pane of a `JFrame` so no need to set it explicitly. I suggest using the `JTextArea` constructor that takes the number of rows and columns rather than setting the size via method `setSize()`. Then call method `pack()` to let _Swing_ set the optimum size.

Comment: This line of the code you posted: `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` needs to come **before** this line: `frame.setVisible(true);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want the text area to be one part of my frame not whole so I wrote textarea.setBounds(10, 120, 80, 180); but it did not work. Any suggestion.

Comment: Use an appropriate layout manager. You hardly ever need to explicitly set sizes and locations for _Swing_ components. Refer to [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code displays a `JTextArea` within a `JScrollPane` in a `JFrame`. Note the order of the code. After adding the `JScrollPane` to the `JFrame`, I call method `pack()` which sets the sizes of the components. After that I call method `setLocationRelativeTo()` and the last method called is `setVisible()`.

All the code that deals with the *Swing* components **must** run on the *Event Dispatch Thread* (EDT). Method `invokeLater()` starts up the EDT and runs the code on that thread.

The result is that the `JFrame` is displayed in the center of the computer screen. You can copy and paste the code and run it.

```java
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class TxtArTst implements Runnable {

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        createAndShowGui();
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JSP");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 80);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        frame.add(scroll);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new TxtArTst());
    }
}
```

### EDIT

This code produces your desired result, according to the image you posted.
Again, you can copy it and run it.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class TxtArTst implements Runnable {

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        createAndShowGui();
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JSP");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 10);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scroll.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 0));
        frame.add(scroll, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        frame.setSize(450, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new TxtArTst());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Suppose we had a frame with the size of (300, 500), and I want to put a text area with the scroll bar in (x=50, y=100) how should we do?

Comment: @HojjatYousefvand why is the size of the `JFrame` so important? I suggest you [edit] your question and post an image of how you want your GUI to look.

Comment: Thanks. I will do.